# C: read struct fraction in procedure

Tags: c, struct, procedure

I'm trying to create a program which reads a number as type fraction using procedures. That's my code (the compiler gives me an error in readFraction() line 9):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int num,den;
} fraction;

void readFraction(fraction * f) {
  printf("Insert a fraction: ");
  scanf("%d/%d", &*f.num, &*f.den);
}

void writeFraction(fraction f) {
  printf("Fraction inserted: %d/%d\n", f.num, f.den);
}

void main() {
  fraction a;

  readFraction(&a);

  writeFraction(a);
}
```

This is the error message:

```
$ gcc fraction.c 
fraction.c: In function ‘readFraction’:
fraction.c:9:21: error: ‘f’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
    9 |   scanf("%d/%d", &*f.num, &*f.den);
      |                     ^
      |                     ->
fraction.c:9:30: error: ‘f’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
    9 |   scanf("%d/%d", &*f.num, &*f.den);
      |                              ^
      |
```

I know I could solve this using something like `readFraction(&a.num,&a.den);` or `a=readFraction();` and the function returns the fraction but I'd like to know if I could just pass the fraction as a parameter.

Comment: fraction.c: In function ‘readFraction’:
fraction.c:9:21: error: ‘f’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   scanf("%d/%d", &*f.num, &*f.den);
                     ^
                     ->
fraction.c:9:30: error: ‘f’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   scanf("%d/%d", &*f.num, &*f.den);
                              ^
                              ->

Comment: What is `&*f.num` supposed to be?

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly what changes you need to make.  Make those changes.

Comment: What do you think "did you mean to use ‘->’? " means when it's pointing to the dot?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I I wanted to assign a value using scanf() to the variable f which points to the variable a in main()

Comment: @bluesaturn And please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add the error message in the future. I fixed it this time.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ok, I'm still learning C, I didn't know about the -> operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is in the relative precedence of C operators.  Structure-member selection has higher precedence than the dereferencing operator, so the sub-expression `*f.num` means "the object to which `f.num` points", not "member `num` of the object to which `f` points."  The former is erroneous because `f` is a pointer, not a structure or union.

You could override the default precedence by adding parentheses:

```
  scanf("%d/%d", &(*f).num, &(*f).den);
```

, but it would be more idiomatic to use the indirect member selection operator:

```
  scanf("%d/%d", &f->num, &f->den);
```

Since we're talking about precedence here, it is worth noting that the `->` operator has higher precedence than `&`, so no parentheses are required in that case.

Comment: Thank you, that totally makes sense!